# How to send multiple messages synchronously?

Tags: synchronization, message, facebook-messenger

I'm using a for-loop to send a large text (larger than 320 chars) in multiple messages, but they land in no-particular order:

```
var arr = ['this', 'is', 'a', 'string'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sendTextMessage(sender, arr[i]);
}
```

Could land as `a, is, this, string`, or any other combination. How do I force them to land in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using the code example from facebook that provides your **sendTextMessage** method. This one acts asynchronously since it uses request module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

If you want to do synchronous calls - means one after another - you've to use another module, e.g. https://github.com/dhruvbird/http-sync

Comment: Thank you. I solved it using a bunch of callbacks, but http-sync looks interesting for this aprticular problem.